# How can I make a compiz window rule for the terminator terminal?

Tags: command-line, compiz, terminator

How can I make a compiz window rule for the terminator terminal?  If you read [this post](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=707664), you will see that terminals will resize uncontrollable.  I am using the terminator terminal and need to set a window rule so it will stop resizing when I open it.

I installed compiz but I can't find instructions on how to set up a rule.  Bill from the linked thread so he was able to solve this problem with window rules which has inspired to do the same except I have no idea on what to do.

I read a few of the post on compiz and window rule but one was close and the others weren't helpful.

Comment: David Timms gave a fuller walk through of Bill's instructions here: <https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=707664#c11> Were you able to follow those instructions?

Comment: No.  I dont understand resize terminal

Comment: Ah, ok. When he says "use mouse to move and resize gnome-terminal to desired pos/size" he means that (1) you can click-and-drag on the Terminal's title bar to move the window around and (2) when you hover the mouse cursor over one of the edges or corners of the window (the mouse cursor will change) you can click-and-drag to manually resize the window.

Comment: I have resized the window correctly but now what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have compiz running...You can try to create a window rule with **compizconfig-settings-manager**

Example:

**1)** Open a Terminal and type:

- `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins`

**2)** Open the compizconfig-settings-manager and go to **Window Management > Window Rules**

[image]

**3)** Click to enable the Window Rules and go to the tab **Size Rules**, then **New**

[image]

**4)** Fill the **Width** and **Height** and click in the **Plus** button

[image]

**5)** Open the application to the rule *(my case gnome-terminal)* and click in the **Grab** button in the new window named "Edit Match". *(I will match with the Window Class)*

[image]

**6)** Now the cursor is a **cross** and click in the application for the rule *(my case gnome-terminal)*

[image]

**7)** To finish.. click in the **Add** button.

**8)** Now in my case when I open the gnome-terminal will be resize to 200x100.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: So I would put terminator-terminal instead of gnome correct?

Comment: @dustin ... yes the gnome-terminal was an example. you should open the terminator terminal and make the rule for it.

Comment: Thanks that worked.  It started to resize but revert right back.

Comment: @dustin. Glad to help...just in case, to revert the changes you should go to the rule and then delete it.

Comment: Hey, nice answer I'm having some trouble with this kind of configuration because the size is being constantly reapplied. So I can't maximize the window if I want to. How can I apply this kind of configuration only when the window is not maximized ?