# Executing wmctrl from bash

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, wmctrl

After playing a little from the terminal with `wmctrl`, now comes the next step.
Execute `wmctrl` from a bash script.

I do achieve to execute `wmctrl` in a bash when it is completely alone.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

 SOUDIR=/usr/bin
 echo "$SOUDIR"
 $SOUDIR/wmctrl -i -r 0x040000b3 -e 0,0,0,500,800
```

But when I add the firefox line code it does not work. I though that adding sleep time would work but I was wrong.

This is the current code:

```
#!/bin/bash

firefox http://www.google.de
sleep 30s
SOUDIR=/usr/bin
echo "$SOUDIR"
$SOUDIR/wmctrl -i -r 0x040000b3 -e 0,0,0,500,800
```

How to resize the web browser using this bash code?

I am new to bash and ubuntu.

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? How are you obtaining the window id 0x040000b3?

Comment: I just want to resize the web browser. That is the ID of the web browser (in this case firefox). Just by typing wmctrl -l you obtain this ID.

Answer (score 1):

OK couple of points:

- You don't need the `/usr/bin` added. Shell will find wmctrl by itself. That's for very specific cases that may involve portability.
- Add ampersand at the end of `firefox` command. The script will proceed only if the previous command exits. Since firefox doesn't exit, the script waits for it.
- As Oli pointed out, better way is to use class name. I've done multiple scripts with `wmctrl` where i find hex id of the window by referencing class name.

Personally I'd do it this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
firefox http://www.google.de &
sleep 3
WM_ID=$(wmctrl -lx | awk '$3~/Navigator.Firefox/ {print $1}')
wmctrl -i -r $WM_ID -e 0,0,0,500,800
```

Here we open firefox , let it run in background, then we extract hex id of the window that matches class `Navigator.Firefox`. In `wmctrl -lx` field 3 is wm_class, and field 1 is hex id. awk helps us to extract field 1 here. Finally we reference that numeric id, inside the final wmctrl statement

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that the `firefox` command would block the script from progressing until it exited. Simply push it into the background and your script can progress:

```
firefox http://www.google.de &
```

On a tangential note, you might also want to look at the [`-no-remote`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#-no-remote) for Firefox. This will stop the command interacting with any existing Firefox instances in your DISPLAY.

While we're talking tangents, the `firefox` command has [a few helper arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#X11_options) that --along with `-no-remote`— can help you target the new window.

For instance, you can set a specific class name and then [have Compiz handle the resizing automagically](https://askubuntu.com/a/345711/449). And `wmctrl -x <WM_CLASS>` will let you target a class rather than an ID. *Probably* more robust than targeting Window names or IDs too.